# Removing audio from video file using melt command

Tags: command-line, video-editing, melt

I have a video file that I am able to play using command

> melt video1.wmv

I want to construct a `melt` command to play video only, I dont want audio of video1.wmv

I tried to follow manual page of `melt` and found something relevant but not working

for example, I found `-video-track | -hide-audio` but I am not able to use this option.

I tried command `melt video.wmv -video-track` and `melt video.wmv -hide-audio` but none is working for.

could anyone tell me right command to see video only using `melt`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer

to play only video

> melt -hide-audio video1.wmv

to play only audio

> melt -hide-video video1.wmv